# npm won't install packages "npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error"

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm

I am having trouble with npm and node version 0.10.40.  I never had this problem before and I am not behind a proxy.  I have tried other solutions that I found on Stack Overflow and other forums such as changing the registry url to  http://.. rather than https://.., and setting strict-ssl to false.  When I do this npm is unable to parse JSON.  Here is my npm-debug.log.  Maybe someone can help me figure out what is going on.

[npm-debug.log](http://pastebin.com/r0tw4vKA)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved this issue by issuing the following commands

```
npm config set proxy false
npm cache clean
```

Apparently npm was attempting to bypass a proxy or believed it was behind a proxy.  Strange.

Answer (score 4):

When you are behind the proxy in a corporate environment you would have used the following commands

> npm config set proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8080
>   npm config set https-proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8080

When you are not just switch the proxy off by

> npm config set proxy false
>     npm cache clean

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is:-

In case your `npm` is unable to build the `phantomJS/CasperJS` packages because of network proxy issue, simply download the `casperjs` and `phantomjs` manually and add to App_data folder in your C:/ folder.

Open your command prompt and execute below code:

```
npm config set proxy false
npm cache clean
```

Add the `casperJS` and `phantomJS` to your PATH variable of your machine.

Run the `casperjs`... problem will be resolved.

Comment: Incase you are going for setting up proxy in your command prompt, make sure there is no @ in your password. for example : if your password is Password@123 , it will not work. Rather first make sure your system password doesnot have any @ in it.

Answer (score 0):

Behind corporate firewall setting proxy also does not works ..try this to get it working ..

http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2017/04/using-npm-behind-a-proxy-that-uses-ntlm-authentication/ http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2017/04/using-npm-behind-a-proxy-that-uses-ntlm-authentication/